# Login failed while connecting to SQL Server database from Cube js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, authentication, cube.js

This is the issue I see in the terminal while i run

```
npm run dev
```

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database. I have changed some settings for my user 'sjeswara' using SSMS which might facilitates connection:

1. Under securities -> Login I have set login as "enabled" for my user.
2. Under security of database property the setting "SQL Server and Window Authentication" property is also checked.

But this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sjeswara'.
>
> at Connection. (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Connection.message (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2148:18)
> at Connection.dispatchEvent (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1279:15)
> at MessageIO. (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1139:14)
> at MessageIO.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Message. (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:46:14)
> at Message.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at endReadableNT (D:\project\cube\testproj\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

Comment: Login failure messages returned to users and applications are, for security reasons, obscure so that hackers aren't given useful information to act upon. Tail the contents of SQL Server's ERRORLOG file for details about login failures (error number 18456). Equipped with the State number from the logged error message you should be able to consult [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual issue.

Comment: I check the logs at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLSERVER2019\MSSQL\Log but it only shows logs for the loging activities I did via SSMS. It doesn't has any of the login attempts I made using Cube.js

Comment: Do you have multiple instance of SQL Server installed? Each instance has its own ERRORLOG file. You can check the `-e` parameter of the service's Startup Parameters tab in Services (service.msc) to locate the full path for each instance's ERRORLOG file.

Comment: I confirmed. Its the same path as I shared before C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLSERVER2019\MSSQL\Log\